# Why doesn't shouldComponentUpdate by default compare nextProps to the current one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm wondering why `shouldComponentUpdate` by default does `return true` when it seems to me like the 1 and only reason not to re-render is if `nextProps` and `this.props` are "equal" in the sense of a deep comparison like

```
function shouldWeRender(prev, next)
{
    return !objectsEqual(prev, next);
}

function objectsEqual(a, b)
{
    var ta = typeof(a), tb = typeof(b);
    if(ta !== 'object' || tb !== 'object') {
        throw 'Arguments must be objects';
    }
    var ka = _.keys(a), kb = _.keys(b);
    if(ka.length !== kb.length) {
       return false;
    }
    _.forEach(ka, function(key) {
        if(!b[key]) {
            return false;
        }
        else if(typeof(a[key] === 'object') && !objectsEqual(a[key], b[key])) {
            return false;
        }
        else if(a[key] !== b[key]) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Shouldn't that be able to work as universal condition for rendering, assuming that we are using stateless components as is proper?

Comment: I think a !== b doesn't necessarily mean they're not equal.

Comment: And herein lies the case for using immutable objects and the effects it has on reconciliation...

Comment: @李骏骁 It does for primitives (non-`object`s)